# Setting up Ubuntu 12.04 to be accessed remotely from anywhere

Tags: 12.04, remote-access

I am extremely new to Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu for the very first time because this is for a school assignment. My main goal right now is to be able to access my Ubuntu desktop remotely from anywhere. I have Ubuntu running in VirtualBox. I have also installed Ubuntu Server, along with MySQL, Apache,and PHP5. In the network settings I have two adapters enabled. The first adapter is for the "bridged-network" and the other is NAT. I have success connecting remotely through my local network, but I want to be able to access Ubuntu from anywhere, using any computer. I am unsure of how to go abouts in doing so. I do feel like I would have to do some port forwarding, but that is all that I am thinking of. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This need to be configured in your router first. It has nothing to do with the OS really. You need to make sure that your router redirects port 22 (for `ssh` access) to your Ubuntu VM. You might want to consider asking this on [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options; I'll list some then you could choose what to apply and look for its detailed steps :

- Install Teamviewer on Linux machine and setup unattended access; then you will be able to access it from anywhere
- Set up your Internet gateway, router, modem... etc with port forwarding then connect to the real IP and the configured port.
- On the Ubuntu machine; you may install VNC server, xRDP, FreeNX...etc

Comment: On the Ubuntu machine, I have installed already VNC Server, and also xrdp. If I wanted to use, for example windows 7 remote desktop connection, port forwarding is the better option?

Comment: If you already has xRDP installed; then sure Port forwarding is the answer. just forward to port 3389 and you are good to go.

Comment: I am new to port forwarding, and I have tried looking online for helpful resources. Don't think that I found any. What is the easiest way, would you say.

Comment: what is your Internet connection type ?

Comment: i have an att uverse 2wire modem. connection type i believe is dsl

Comment: you need to know the brand of your ADSL modem router and refer back to its manual or call ISP for assistance, you also need to have a static IP assigned to your modem that you will use to connect.

Comment: If above are problimatic, then I would suggest using Teamviewer as it doesn't require static IP and is quite easy to setup and use.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13464/discussion-between-ahmadgeo-and-beginnerprogrammer)